# Are foreign keys used in a "link" table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Quick question about DB design!  In this example there are users and schedules.  Each user can have many schedules and each schedule can belong to many users.

I have two tables, 'user' and 'schedule', that each have a unique identifier/primary key (user_id and schedule_id): these tables have a many-to-many relationship.

This is where I am unsure/inexperienced: In order to connect them together and adhere to good db design, I want to create a link table that has two columns, user_id and schedule_id.  I plan to make these both primary keys (therefore a composite key).  However, do I also add two foreign keys, one on user_id linked to the 'user' table and one on schedule_id linked to the 'schedule' table?

TLDR:  I plan to use a composite key in 2-column 'link' table that connects two tables. Should/Do I also need to make those into foreign keys?

Comment: The answer to all your questions is Yes.

Comment: Your thinking is exactly correct - a composite primary key to ensure unique pairs, with a foreign key to each of the other tables ensuring referential integrity with them.\

Comment: Thank you, tried searching for that everywhere and couldn't find a concrete response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PKs and FKs serve different purposes. In a link table, you need the PK to preserve uniqueness of the data. However, if you do not also create the FKs then you may end up with data integrity problems because the ID could be deleted from the original table and not the link table.

Sometimes people think they can get away without the FKs because they will enforce data integrity through the application. Almost always this is because they find it annoying when the constraints won't let them do something they want to do. Of course that is the purpose of the constraint, to prevent users and developers from doing things they should not. Data integrity must be preserved through the database; it is too important to risk letting the application handle it. I have seen a lot of data from hundreds of databases and the ones with the worst data are invariably the ones where the devs thought they could manage stuff like table relationships through the application. There are always holes when you do this and eventually they come back to bite you and then they can be very difficult to fix properly.

Comment: +1: I'd just add that applications simply cannot enforce integrity between rows (primary, unique, and foreign keys) because databases prevent sessions from seeing uncommitted changes. Two sessions can simultaneously enter the same data without being able to detect that the other has done so.